# Selenium Firefox Not Working When Disconnected From Remote Desktop (RDP)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, vps

I am automating a process using Selenium Firefox and Python. I am running Selenium on a Google Virtual Instance and accessing using RDP. All went fine when I ran it through RDP, but the problem is when I disconnect from RDP, Selenium doesn't work.

The part of selenium that doesn't work is :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By. CSS_SELECTOR,'div.van-key__wrapper:nth-child(9) div:nth-child(1)'))).click()
```

I have tested everything all over the internet like gpedit regedit everything and also not tell to put bat file or command to stay connected to local user like chromedriver (selenium).

Comment: I Have a dedicated server. happens to me too.